# Adding "related pages" to all pages (including views, module pages, etc.)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 site that includes many types of pages - some nodes, many are Views, and some are generated by my custom module. Now, a large portion of them includes the same "related links" box - a list of links to nodes that I want to control directly on a per-page basis. Currently, I have a "related pages" field on all of my node types, and I add this section manually on Views' footers and in module pages.

Is there a better way? Perhaps something that could assign a list of nodes to a specific URL?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to add the related links to the nodes?  Are you just putting the URL in that node ?

Comment: At the moment, just a node reference field with multiple values

Comment: Each content type have a related links page or each page?  Maybe try to add taxonomy to the pages and group them by a term.  Then pull the views in by related terms?